# for each loop container SSIS

Tags: ssis

Is there any way to skip processed file's placed in a folder and only process new file in For each loop container in SSIS. Rather then Looping all the files just loop through the unprocessed file.

Comment: That depends how you recognise that a file is processed. The standard way to do this is move processed files to a _different_ folder when done. You'll see that in most for each loop examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:
Move the processed files to an archive folder. This will make sure that you always process the new files.